# Django: How can you get the current URL tagname (for pagination)?

Tags: django, django-templates, pagination, django-urls

I'm trying to do pagination with the page parameter in the URL (instead of the GET parameter). I also want my pagination to be shared code across multiple different templates.

Given that, I think I need to do something like this :

urls.py:

```
url(r'^alias/page;(?P<page>[0-9]+)/(?P<id>.*)$', alias.get, name="alias"),
```

tempaltes/alias.html:

```
<div>...stuff...</div>
{% include "paginator.html" %}
```

templates/paginator.html :

```
{% if page_obj.has_previous or page_obj.has_next %}
{% load filters %}
<div class="pagination clear">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a href="{% url somemagic %}" class="prev">&lsaquo;&lsaquo; previous</a>
...
```

What is `somemagic`?

Assume I want to keep my url the same except set the page `page_obj.previous_page_number`

Comment: Have you already looked into django-pagination as an alternative option?
http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/

Comment: Yes, it uses ?page=4 but I have other persistent get parameters that will get in the way.

Comment: are your other get parameters 'page'? django-pagination will keep all the other get parameters intact. i use it on every app ever. you can't lose if you watch these screencasts. http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/first-two-django-screencasts/

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

You need *`somemagic`* to be a variable with the name of the current view.

Try this:

```
{% with request.path_info|resolve_url_name as current_view %}
    {% url current_view page_obj.previous_page_number object.id %}
{% endwith %}
```

You can get this working with some code from django-snippets:

1. [Variable resolving URL template tag](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1359/) Makes the {% url %} tag resolve variables from  context.
2. [Resolve URLs to view name](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1378/) The function `resolve_to_name(path)` returns the view name for `path`. You just need to create a filter that uses this function.

This solution wont work with urls like:

```
'alias/param1_regexp/param2_regexp/page;(?P<page>[0-9]+)/(?P<id>.*)$'
```

because you've no clue about param1 and param2.

A modification can be done to the django-snippets above to make this kind of urls work:

**First snippet modifications:**

```
from django.template import defaulttags, VariableDoesNotExist, Variable

class ResolvingURLNode(defaulttags.URLNode):
    def render(self, context):
        original_view_name = self.view_name
        try:
            resolved = Variable(self.view_name).resolve(context)
            if len(resolved) > 1:                
                self.view_name = resolved[0]
                if resolved[1]:
                    self.args = [Variable(arg) for arg in resolved[1]]
            elif len(resolved) > 0:
                self.view_name = resolved[0]
            else:
                self.view_name = resolved

        except VariableDoesNotExist:
            pass
        ret = super(defaulttags.URLNode, self).render(context)
        # restore view_name in case this node is reused (e.g in a loop) in
        # which case the variable might resolve to something else in the next iteration)
        self.view_name = original_view_name
        return ret

defaulttags.URLNode = ResolvingURLNode
```

**Second snippet modifications**

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import RegexURLResolver, RegexURLPattern, Resolver404, get_resolver

__all__ = ('resolve_to_name',)

def _pattern_resolve_to_name(self, path):
    match = self.regex.search(path)
    if match:
        name = ""
        if self.name:
            name = self.name
        elif hasattr(self, '_callback_str'):
            name = self._callback_str
        else:
            name = "%s.%s" % (self.callback.__module__, self.callback.func_name)
        if len(match.groups()) > 0:
            groups = match.groups()
        else:
            groups = None
        return name, groups


def _resolver_resolve_to_name(self, path):
    tried = []
    match = self.regex.search(path)
    if match:
        new_path = path[match.end():]
        for pattern in self.url_patterns:
            try:
                resolved = pattern.resolve_to_name(new_path)
                if resolved:
                    name, groups = resolved
                else:
                    name = None
            except Resolver404, e:
                tried.extend([(pattern.regex.pattern + '   ' + t) for t in e.args[0 ['tried']])
            else:
                if name:
                    return name, groups
                tried.append(pattern.regex.pattern)
        raise Resolver404, {'tried': tried, 'path': new_path}


# here goes monkeypatching
RegexURLPattern.resolve_to_name = _pattern_resolve_to_name
RegexURLResolver.resolve_to_name = _resolver_resolve_to_name


def resolve_to_name(path, urlconf=None):
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve_to_name(path)
```

Basically, resolve_to_name returns the name of the view and it's parameters as a tuple, and the *new* `{% url myvar %}` takes this tuple and uses it to reverse the path with the view name and it's parameters.

If you don't like the filter approach it can also be done with a custom middleware.

---

**Previous answer**

You should check django-pagination, it's a really nice django application, easy tu use and gets the job done.

With django pagination the code to paginate an iterable would be:

`{% load pagination_tags %}`

`{% autopaginate myiterable 10 %} <!-- 10 elements per page -->`

`{% for item in myiterable %}`
`RENDERING CONTENT`
`{% endfor %}`

`{% paginate %} <!-- this renders the links to navigate through the pages -->`

*myiterable* can be anything that is iterable:list, tuple, queryset, etc

The project page at googlecode:
http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/

Comment: yes, I was using that, but it has ?page= as the way to paginate which doesn't work for me as my urls already have some query parameters that are important to preserve.

Comment: Interesting, why isn't this type of {% url %} in actual django? And for the middleware approach, would it be less invasive? Rewriting the core {% url %} seems like it might break something down the road.

Comment: With a middleware, instead of using request.path_info|resolve_to_url you will call resolve_to_url(request.path_info) in the middleware process_request(request) method, and add it to the request as a custom variable. Then it would be available in any template of your project.

The new {% url %} will fail if you have a view and a variable with the same name.

You can avoid this by creating your custom templatetag {% myurl %} and use this or the default one as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like the following. Except I don't know what you mean by id so I just put a generic object id. The syntax for url is {% url view_name param1 param2 ... %}

```
{% url alias page_obj.previous_page_number object.id %}
```

Updated base on your need:

```
{% url alias page_obj.previous_page_number object.id as prev_url %}
{% include "paginator.html" %}
...
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a href="{{prev_url}}" class="prev">&lsaquo;&lsaquo; previous</a>
```

Comment: But pagination.html will be included from many other files for many other urls (with different template names). So I can't just put "alias" in there.